# Topology definition: finite intersections vs. infinite unions

Tags: general-topology

In the definition of topology, we allow infinite unions but only allow finite intersections. As mentioned by many other answers (see [In a topological space, why the intersection only has to be finite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284970/in-a-topological-space-why-the-intersection-only-has-to-be-finite); [Why Use Arbitrary Unions and Finite Intersections in Topology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165829/why-use-arbitrary-unions-and-finite-intersections-in-topology)), it is said that we want to **keep the sets to be open set after the allowed operation**. But the infinite intersection of open sets can be a close set. The example is given:
\begin{equation}\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(a-\frac{1}{n},b+\frac{1}{n})=[a,b],\quad (b>a)\end{equation}
**The question is: what is the answer of 
\begin{equation}\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n})=?\quad (b>a+2)\end{equation}
is it $[a,b]$ or $(a,b)$?**

If it is $(a,b)$ , seems that we use a different rule of limitation between intersection and union; if it is  $[a,b]$，seems that we get a close set by operations (allowed by topology) on the open sets.

Comment: If it were $[a,b]$ then $a$ would have to be an element of $(a+1/n,b-1/n)$ for some $n$. Which $n$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I am not very clear about your question. For infinite intersection, I guess this is an agreed result. There is not actual $n$ there. It's just like a limitation. For  infinite unions, I thought we can use the same argument.

Comment: You can get a closed set by operating on open sets. For example, $(-\infty, 1) \cup (-1, \infty)$ and $(1,2) \cap (3,4)$ are both closed sets. (they are also both open sets)

Comment: @XLiu: Infinite unions and intersections are *not* limits. These are operations performed on the *entire* family of sets. They are *not* some notion of a "limit" of partial unions or partial intersections of finitely many sets.

Comment: That make sense. Can you tell me how can we think it for the intersection? Seems that we always have $a-\epsilon$ belong to the result. So the result is always a little bigger than $[a,b]$ for the intersection?@Hurkyl

Comment: You seem to be a bit fuzzy about the definitions of infinite union and intersection. For a family of sets $A_i$, with $i \in I$, the union $\cup_{i \in I} A_i$ is just the set of elements that belong to *at least one* of the $A_i$. Likewise, the intersection $\cap_{i \in I} A_i$ is the set of elements that belong to *all* of the $A_i$.

Comment: @Sambo I agree with you about that. Seems that my question does not confuse with this? Please notice that I change the sign of the lower boundary from subtraction to addition when I change from intersection to union.

Comment: Your question doesn't make mistakes about these definitions; however, to figure out the answer to your question, you just need to take a look at the definition. As Lord Shark puts it, if $a$ is in the union of your sets, it must belong to one of them. Which one?

Comment: @Hurkyl So why we ask inifinite unions but finite intersections by the definition? The results of two examples you given are the whole set and the empty set, they are both close set and open set. So they dont disgree with the motivation - **keep the sets to be open set after the allowed operation.**

Comment: @XLiu The motivation to "keep the sets open" still works, since an important thing to consider is that a set can be *both open and closed*. This is what happens in Hurkyl's examples. The resulting sets are closed, yes, but they are also open. The set obtained by infinite intersection that you described in your question, on the other hand, is *not open*.

Comment: @Sambo This make sense. With others answers I now know clearly the difference.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, 
$$\left(a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}  \right)\subset (a,b)  $$.

Thus,

$$ \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\left(a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}  \right) \subset (a,b)$$.

Conversely, if $x\in (a,b)$, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subset (a,b)$. Then there exists $N_1,N_2\in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$b-\epsilon-x > \frac{1}{N_1},\hspace{2mm} \frac{1}{N_2}<x-\epsilon-a $$

Let $N=\max(N_1,N_2)$, then

$$b-\frac{1}{N}>x+\epsilon \text{ and } x-\epsilon > a+\frac{1}{N}$$, so

$$ x\in (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subset \left(a+\frac{1}{N},b-\frac{1}{N}\right)\subset  \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\left(a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}  \right)$$.

Thereforem

$$(a,b)= \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\left(a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}  \right)$$

Comment: This make sense. So this is like to say $x\in(a+\epsilon,b-\epsilon)$ for unions. The limitation is $(a,b)$; while $x\in(a-\epsilon,b+\epsilon)$ for intersection, which always includes $[a,b]$, and in limitation should be $[a,b]$? @LevBan

Comment: Yes $$ \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\left(a-\frac{1}{n},b+\frac{1}{n}\right)=[a,b]$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\left(a+\frac1n,b-\frac1n\right)&=(a+1,b-1)\cup\left(a+\frac12,b-\frac12\right)\cup\ldots\\&=(a,b).\end{align}In fact:

1. $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):\left(a+\frac1n,b-\frac1n\right)\subset(a,b)$;
2. if $x\geqslant b$ or $x\leqslant a$, then $x$ belongs to no interval of the form $\left(a+\frac1n,b-\frac1n\right)$;
3. if $x\in(a,b)$, there's a $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $x\in\left(a+\frac1n,b-\frac1n\right)$, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}a+\frac1n=a$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}b-\frac1n=b$.

So, the union of all these open sets is again an open set and furthermore it is *not* a closed set.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, for every $n \in \Bbb N = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$,

$\left (a + \dfrac{1}{n}, b - \dfrac{1}{n} \right ) = \left \{ x \in \Bbb R \mid a + \dfrac{1}{n} < x < b - \dfrac{1}{n} \right \}; \tag 1$

thus it is easy to see that

$\forall n \in \Bbb N, \; a, b \notin \left (a + \dfrac{1}{n}, b - \dfrac{1}{n} \right ); \tag 2$

it then follows that

$a, b \notin \displaystyle \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} \left (a + \dfrac{1}{n}, b - \dfrac{1}{n} \right ); \tag 3$

however, we do have

$y \in (a, b) \Longrightarrow \exists n \in \Bbb N, \; y \in  \left \{ x \in \Bbb R \mid a + \dfrac{1}{n} < x < b - \dfrac{1}{n} \right \} = \left (a + \dfrac{1}{n}, b - \dfrac{1}{n} \right ), \tag 4$

from which

$y \in (a, b) \Longrightarrow y \in \displaystyle \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} \left (a + \dfrac{1}{n}, b - \dfrac{1}{n} \right ) \Longrightarrow (a, b) \subset \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} \left (a + \dfrac{1}{n}, b - \dfrac{1}{n} \right ), \tag 5$

and since for every $n \in \Bbb N$ we clearly have

$\left (a + \dfrac{1}{n}, b - \dfrac{1}{n} \right ) \subset (a, b), \tag 6$

we may infer that

$\displaystyle \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} \left (a + \dfrac{1}{n}, b - \dfrac{1}{n} \right ) \subset (a, b); \tag 7$

therefore,

$(a, b) = \displaystyle \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} \left (a + \dfrac{1}{n}, b - \dfrac{1}{n} \right ), \tag 8$

and from (3) we see that

$[a, b] \ne \displaystyle \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} \left (a + \dfrac{1}{n}, b - \dfrac{1}{n} \right ). \tag 9$

In conclusion, we observe that there is in fact a different "rule of limitation" between intersection and union, since an infinite *union* of open sets must be open, but an infinite *intersection* of open sets may indeed be closed.